# modulus algorithm going through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I expect the result to be 3,1,0,0 but it gave me 3,1,1,1 instead. Anything wrong with my algorithm below using modulus?

```
points = [6,5,4,2];
var arr = [];
points.forEach(function (obj, i) {
    var a = 21;
    a = a % points[i] || "";

    arr.push(a);

});

console.log(arr);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ufegq7kp/

Comment: Why would you expect ` 3,1,0,0 ` Please explain clearly

Comment: 3,1,1,1 is the correct modulus for the numbers you provided

Comment: I expect that because after I got the first result which is 3, it will continue with 5 % 3.

Answer (score 5):

```
In [1]: 21 % 6
Out[1]: 3

In [2]: 21 % 5
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: 21 % 4
Out[3]: 1

In [4]: 21 % 2
Out[4]: 1
```

Your output is the expected output.

**Unrelated:** Instead of looking up the value by index from points, you already have the value in your `forEach` function as `obj`:

```js
var points = [6,5,4,2],
    arr = [];

points.forEach(function (obj) {
    var a = 21;
    a = a % obj || "";
    arr.push(a);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly.  There is nothing wrong with the JavaScript code.  @aviatewong please review how the modulus operator works.

Comment: I expect 3,1,0,0 because after I got the first result which is 3, it will continue with 5 % 3. how to produce that result ?

Comment: Can you explain why the second operation would be 5 % 3?

Comment: 5 is the second array item and 3 is used when 20 % 6 = 2;

Comment: Can you explain the algorithm? From what you have provided so far the 3rd operation is still undeterminable.

Answer (score 1):

The modulus returns the remainder of the divide.

```
21 / 6 = 3 (remainder 3)
       21 % 6 = 3
21 / 5 = 4 (remainder 1)
       21 % 5 = 1
21 / 4 = 5 (remainder 1)
       21 % 4 = 1
21 / 2 = 10 (remainder 1)
       21 % 2 = 1
```

There is nothing wrong with your modulus or the way you use it. The result you are expecting is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

*forEach* prototype take two argument *element, index*. So you can use *element* value for the every iteration.

View: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ufegq7kp/1/)

> **index** - The index of the current element being processed in the array.
>
> **element** - actual element value of current element.

```
points = [6,5,4,2];
var arr = [];
points.forEach(function (element, index) {
    var a = 21;
    a = a % element || "";
    arr.push(a);

});

console.log(arr);
```

JavaScript [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) Doc

Comment: Please stop using `<kbd>` tags to highlight links in your posts. That is not what they're for.

Comment: The downvote existed April 17th, **8 days** before I left my comment. I didn't give you any down votes.